# file data from start not passed to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have an existing log file and I am setting up ELK stack now and I am able to connect everything together and anything I add does reflect in Elasticsearch,
But data that was already there in the log file does not show up in Elasticsearch

logstash.conf file
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/ubuntu/cms_access.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "xyz.com:80"
    user => 'kibanauser'
    password => 'password'
    document_type => "_doc"
  }
}

I am checking this using Kibana and I do not find the data there so any assistance on this will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

the logstash.conf file needs to have start_position and sincedb_path as below .. insufficient research on my part but hope this helps someone

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/ubuntu/apache-daily-access.log"
  start_position => "beginning"
  sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
```